# Why is there space between elements within my table cell

Tags: css, html, html-table, html-email

I am new to html and in fact just today figured out the concept behind making tables and combining cells and columns to place things correctly.

A little backstory, I am creating a newsletter header that goes out from our newsletter system to emails. This is meant to be viewed in email and from what I am told our Email Newsletter system does not support divs, so I have to use Table. Secondly our newsletter system does not accept what i am calling (probably wrongfully so) "Global Css Styles" and so everything has to be in line. For instance when this is fixed, I will have to go align each element to center individually for whatever reason.

Now for my problem, The company logo is all the way to the left, and the other elements are all the way to the right. Except, the facebook, twitter, and linkedin logo all have a very small space between them. Now I have tried and tried and tried to search for a solution.

- "Space between elements in a table cell HTML"
- "Space between elements within a table cell html"
- "remove space between html elements" (turned up results but couldn't get it to work for me)
- and many others...

Please help me, I don't understand this at all....

```html
<table id="Header" width="700" height="75" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
  <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">
    <a href="https://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/home.asp" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderLTILogoWeb.png" height="75" width="250">
    </a>
  </td>
  
  <td valign="top" align="right" width="" height="36">
    <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_01.png" width="135" height="36">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/linktechnologiesinc/" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_02.png" width="42" height="36">
      </a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/linktechsdotnet" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_03.png" width="38" height="36">
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company-beta/9211300/" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_04.png" width="41" height="36">
      </a> 
    </td>
  </tr>
 
  <tr align="right">
    <td colspan="3" align="right" valign="top">
      <a href="tel:314-7350270" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_05.png" width="113" height="39">
      </a>
      <a href="mailto:sales@linktechs.net" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_06.png" width="143" height="39">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<!--LINKS TO HEADER FILES IN ORDER
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderLTILogoWeb.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_01.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_02.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_03.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_04.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_05.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_06.png
-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual spaces in your HTML code between the `<img>` and `<a>` elements are becoming visible gaps between each of the icons. There are a few ways you could go about fixing this:

1. Eliminate spaces and line breaks in the HTML itself in this area. You could still space out elements using HTML comments (`<!-- -->`) for organization, and put line breaks in there.
2. Put `style="font-size: 0;"` inline on the `<td>` holding those images, to see  if it eliminates the size of the gaps.
3. Use CSS `float` to have the links/images flush up against one another, by putting `style="float: left;"` on each link.

Here's solution #2 implemented (`font-size: 0`) on the social media button section for demonstration:

```html
<table id="Header" width="700" height="75" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <a href="https://www.linktechs.net/productcart/pc/home.asp" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderLTILogoWeb.png" height="75" width="250">
      </a>
    </td>

    <td valign="top" align="right" width="" height="36" style="font-size: 0;">
      <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_01.png" width="135" height="36">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/linktechnologiesinc/" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_02.png" width="42" height="36">
      </a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/linktechsdotnet" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_03.png" width="38" height="36">
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company-beta/9211300/" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_04.png" width="41" height="36">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr align="right">
    <td colspan="3" align="right" valign="top">
      <a href="tel:314-7350270" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_05.png" width="113" height="39">
      </a>
      <a href="mailto:sales@linktechs.net" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_06.png" width="143" height="39">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<!--LINKS TO HEADER FILES IN ORDER
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderLTILogoWeb.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_01.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_02.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_03.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_04.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_05.png
http://news.linktechs.net/uploadedimages/000002/Newsletter/00-Permanent-Assets/NewHeaderSlice2_06.png
-->
```

Comment: Correction on my first comment. Sorry.

Ok, That seems silly... especially because w3 schools (which i am using to learn) has this "With HTML, you cannot change the output by adding extra spaces or extra lines in your HTML code."  Thank you for the help! 

If someone can explain as to why spaces are now making a difference that would be great... everything i know (not much) has been learned from reading w3 schools tutorial. This examples just seems to me that w3 schools just plain got it wrong.

Your a life saver! Thanks so much!

Comment: @AlexAmbrose Glad I could help! W3Schools isn't affiliated with the W3C and they're not regarded as an excellent resource - you can read more here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com .  As for what they were probably trying to say, multiple spaces or line breaks are consolidated into a single space, so "extra spaces" won't do anything. Since my answer helped, please feel free to mark it as having solved your question. Thank you!